# Primefaces Custom icon in commanbutton

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want a PNG File (26*26px) as background of my Primefaces Button.

this is my css class

```
.btnCreate {
border-radius: 0px;
background-image: url("#{resource['images/create.png']}") !important;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
}
```

and this would be the Button

```
<p:commandButton icon="btnCreate" title="Icon Only" />
```

Here is the outcome:

[outcome](http://i.imgur.com/hPbQQK0.jpg)

How can I position the Image in the middle of the button?

**Edit2:** As some people suggested I tried changing values @background-position but that didn't help either since it was just cutting the image and display only the right or left border

[outcome after back-position:-10px-10](http://i.imgur.com/VzaX1cA.jpg)

Comment: use like this
<a href="#"><img src="images/create.png" alt="Create" /></a>

Comment: @Sushan this is not plain html, he uses jsf and primefaces

Comment: @Theo sure that happens, because you said ure picture is 26*26px if you now substract 10px you get that outcome. i updatet my post, please retry

Answer (score 0):

Some fancy stuff is going on here, may try

```
    <p:commandButton icon="btnCreate" title="Icon Only"
        styleClass="btnCreate" style="width:26px; height:26px" />
```

CSS:

> .btnCreate {  border-radius: 0px;     background:
>   url(resources/images/create.png); no-repeat !important;
>     background-position: 0 0 !important;    border: 0px; }

works for me under 3.5 now

Comment: it remains the same way... I tried toying around with the background-position but it didn't really help, it just cuts my image

Comment: @theo did you use !important after the backgroundposition?

Comment: Yes... still the same :(

Comment: I could post the png on imgur and you can try it urself:) [here you go](http://i.imgur.com/XlLgUHJ.png) and thanks for helping

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using? on my version it works fine

Comment: @theo looks like you dont use the right path of the picture

Comment: I copied ur code. why would the path be the problem when the png is loaded tho?:)

Comment: Because i am using a different path? I got a folder called ressources in there, you not

Comment: my full path is resources/images/create.png

Answer (score 0):

Just use `background-position` :

```
.btnCreate {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-image: url("#{resource['images/create.png']}") !important;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-position: -10px -10px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here you have the full example:

First create the button with icon only:

```
<p:commandButton icon="btnCreate" title="Icon Only"  styleClass="iconOnlyButton"/>
```

Now, define style for button with icon only:

```
.iconOnlyButton{
    background: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And Icon:

```
.btnCreate {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/create.png']}") !important;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Add styles for button like `border` , `background-color` etc to **iconOnlyButton** class in CSS. In **btnCreate** keep only attributes for your image. You can adjust `background-position` on the fly in any modern browser like Chrome or Firefox

Comment: I edited my anserw - I believe it explains more now.

Comment: edit2: thanks, I think I'm getting closer [this is what I get now](http://imgur.com/UTiB8DJ)

Comment: Try to experiment with ``background-position`` - for example ``-3px -3px``;